# How to add something to a file line by line in C++?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, edit

Let's consider I have this .txt file:

```
one
two
three
```

And like to make a file like this from that:

```
<s> one </s> (1)
<s> one </s> (2)
<s> one </s> (3)
<s> two </s> (1)
<s> two </s> (2)
<s> two </s> (3)
<s> three </s> (1)
<s> three </s> (2)
<s> three </s> (3)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? How did that work? How didn't that work? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [stream iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to first read your input file into a `std::vector` storing each line:

```
using inliner = std::istream_iterator<Line>;

std::vector<Line> lines{
    inliner(stream),
    inliner() // end-of-stream iterator
};
```

With the structure `Line` declaring needed `operator>>` based on [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
struct Line
{
    std::string content;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Line& line)
    {
        return std::getline(is, line.content);
    }
};
```

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Line
{
    std::string content;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Line& line)
    {
        return std::getline(is, line.content);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::istringstream stream("one\ntwo\nthree");

    using inliner = std::istream_iterator<Line>;

    std::vector<Line> lines{
        inliner(stream),
        inliner()
    };

    for(auto& line : lines)
    {
        int i = 1;
        std::cout << "<s> " << line.content << " </s> (" << i << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

To complete your work, change the string stream for a file stream, and outputs the completed result into a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Unfortunately I have 11+ reputations and I can not give a positive score to your post. but I will do it when I reached to 15.